# @RequiresDevice not honored by new Emualtor?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-testing

After upgrading to Android Studio 2.0, my tests that are annotated with `@RequiresDevice` are now running with the 2.0 emulators.  Is there some switches I should use in the emulator to make it a emulator again?

Comment: If you haven't already, please file a bug for it [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Test%20Support%20Library%20bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because I did not use the latest support library of test runner and test rules, annotations.  Upgrading to latest (version number at the date of this writing):
`com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0
com.android.support.test:runner:0.5.0
com.android.support.test:rules:0.5.0`

fixes the issue.

Comment: I had to use the following:  androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test:runner0.5")
androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test:rules:0.5")